# My SerialDataEventHandler works just once

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port

i've an issue with my SerialDataEventHandler, it works just once, let me explain with the following code :

```
    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //init serialport comport
        SerialPort comport = (SerialPort)sender;

        // Shortened and error checking removed for brevity...
        if (!comport.IsOpen) return;
        int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        HandleSerialData(buffer, comport);
        comport.DataReceived -=
            new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    public void HandleSerialData(byte[] respBuffer, SerialPort comport)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(respBuffer.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in respBuffer)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

        string hex2 = hex.ToString();
        hex2 = hex2.Substring(22, 8);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { EnOcean_Label.Content = hex2; }));
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { EnOcean2_Label.Content = hex2; }));
    }
```

So, i register my data in a datagrid but it doesn't matter here, my only issue is that, my code works just once, and it need to work "forever" after the first call what function/method should I use for let the program get new data from my SerialPort.

Comment: What on earth made you decide to unsubscribe the event?  That hex2.SubString() call can never work correctly, you normally only get 1 or 2 bytes.  Seems to work okay when you debug and make your program intentionally slow by single-stepping, won't work when it runs at full speed.   You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: my telegram is only 24 bytes each time the user press a physical button, don't see why substring is a problem

Comment: *you normally only 1 or 2 bytes*.  Not 24.  Serial ports implement a simple byte stream, just like TCP, it knows nothing about "telegrams".  You have to count them off yourself, store them in a byte[].  And not call HandleSerialData() until you got all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You only only receive data notification event once because you're unsubscribing from the `DataReceived` at its first occurrence. Remove

```
    comport.DataReceived -=
        new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

from `DataReceivedHandler`.